# gulp stream does not generate dest files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

There is a bug in following gulp stream but I just couldn't find where.

```js
var processors = [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version']}),
                  cssnano(),];

var myjob = gulp.src(['app/css/normalize.css',
                      'app/css/org.scss'])
        .pipe(watch('app/css/org.scss', {verbose: true}))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.scss', sass()))
        .pipe(concat('org.css'))
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

**Problem**: The `dist/org.css` is not regenerated

there must be something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `gulp-concat` doesn't push the concatenated `org.css` file unless it receives an `end` event from upstream. Since `gulp-watch` never emits the `end` event, `gulp-concat` just hangs indefinitely.

The solution is to simply replace `gulp-concat` with [`gulp-continuous-concat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-continuous-concat):

```
var continuousConcat = require('gulp-continuous-concat');

var processors = [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version']}),
                  cssnano(),];

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src(['app/css/normalize.css',
                   'app/css/org.scss'])
    .pipe(watch('app/css/org.scss', {verbose: true}))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.scss', sass()))
    .pipe(continuousConcat('org.css'))
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice use the glob root "./" to prefix your paths. i.e. "./app/css/normalize.css" and so on.

Try and use [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) to see how many files are in the pipe, if any. You can add a debug pipe between each step to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the glob tip.  I will fix that.  And I did use `gulp-debug`, it outputs the file name but no file generated.  @Sven Schcenung's answer solves my problem.